# Firmware Compatibility with 15.x IOS versions

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, cisco-ios-15, firmware

I have a Cisco switch stack with both PoE and non-PoE switches as members. Is there any compatibility issues with the firmware version 15.0.2-SE11 between the following devices?

```
1x Cisco WS-C3750G-48TS  (Non-PoE)
&
3x Cisco WS-C3750G-48PS  (PoE capable)
```

I see on the Cisco site that for both types of switches they offer the same version to download, but was wondering if there was any difference in compatibility between the 48TS and 48PS when I go to download those files?

**Bonus:** Assuming that the versions are compatible with each other and run typical operations, would there be any feature conflict between the two devices?  Lets say, when I go to run any scripts via IOS.sh, will I run into any problems then? Will the 48TS react differently than the 48PS depending on the script ran?

If so, is it easier in the long run to avoid those possible issues and swap out the one existing 48TS switch with another 48PS switch to match the rest of the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any compatibility issues with the firmware version
>   15.0.2-SE11 between the following devices?

There are no compatibility issues, as long as the software and basic model is identical. You can mix various types of switches and we use that feature a lot in our organization.

> I see on the Cisco site that for both types of switches they offer the
>   same version to download, but was wondering if there was any
>   difference in compatibility between the 48TS and 48PS when I go to
>   download those files?

The software is the same for each model train. When the switch is upgraded and the new software initialized, the IOS will identify the switch model and activate/disable the features applicable for that specific model. Cisco has used this method for a very long time now.

> Assuming that the versions are compatible with each other and run
>   typical operations, would there be any feature conflict between the
>   two devices?

No, this will not cause any problems.

> If so, is it easier in the long run to avoid those possible issues and
>   swap out the one existing 48TS switch with another 48PS switch to
>   match the rest of the stack?

In my 15+ years in the network field we've never had any problems regarding mixing various switch models within the same model train.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix POE and Non-POE SW. 

The difference between POE SW is whether power is supplied or not. 

You can use either of the interface `power inline xxx` commands. However, when the Interface is not POE capable,  I think that command will reject.  
Something like this. 1/0/1 is POE

```
interface gigabitethernet1/0/1
  desc xxx
  inline power xxx
...
interface gigabitethernet2/0/1
  desc xxx
```

You can also check the interface power state with the `show power inline` command.